# Keyboard shortcut to "add to watch" in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is there any keyboard shortcut to add the highlighted variable to watch in VS IDE? It takes a bit of time to right click and choosing "Add to watch" option in the very long drop down menu and its annoying.

-Thanks,
Suresh.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not by default.

You can add one: Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard and enter "watch" in the "show commands..." box. You need the "Debug.AddWatch" command.

Comment: Thank You richard.

Answer (score 3):

Go to menu: **Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard**

search for "watch" and the **Debug.Addwatch** will be revealed. Add an assigned shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

You can just highlight & drag and drop the variable into the watch window.

Comment: Asker specifically wants a keyboard shortcut.